# NameError (uninitialized constant Many-To-Many) Mono-transitive association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My many to many associations seem not to be working. 
An example is this: where TasksTestMethods is the JoinTable

```
TasksTestMethods.all 
TasksTestMethods Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "tasks_test_methods".* FROM "tasks_test_methods" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<TasksTestMethods task_id: 2, test_method_id: 1>]>
```

The join table in schema.rb looks like this

```
create_table "tasks_test_methods", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "task_id", null: false
    t.bigint "test_method_id", null: false
    t.index ["task_id", "test_method_id"], name: "index_tasks_test_methods_on_task_id_and_test_method_id"
    t.index ["test_method_id", "task_id"], name: "index_tasks_test_methods_on_test_method_id_and_task_id"
  end
```

Now when I want to query for TestMethods for task with id of 2 as seen above.

```
task = Task.last
Task Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" ORDER BY "tasks"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Task id: 2, name: "", description: "", start_date: "2018-05-15", end_date: nil, order_number: "", material_type: nil, client_id: 1, drawing_number: nil, task_status_field: nil, invoice_number: nil, offshore_flag: 0, client_ref: "", contact_person: "", contact_person_phone: "", contact_person_email: "", testsite: "", information_to_operator: nil, client_online_order: nil, start_date_asap: nil, thickness: nil, testextent: nil, groove: nil, material_quality: nil, class_society: nil, welder_id: nil, project_id: nil, operator_id: nil, task_manager_id: 1, department_id: 5, created_at: "2018-05-14 22:13:08", updated_at: "2018-05-14 22:18:30", language_id: 2>
```

I get the following error when I run it like this

```
task.test_methods
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):6
NameError (uninitialized constant Task::TasksTestMethod)
```

Same when I try for TestMethod

```
test_method = TestMethod.last
  TestMethod Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "test_methods".* FROM "test_methods" ORDER BY "test_methods"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<TestMethod id: 1, name: "Visual Testing (VT)", code: nil, description: nil, category_id: 1, procedure_id: 1, created_at: "2018-05-15 07:06:51", updated_at: "2018-05-15 07:06:51">
```

I get this error:

```
test_method.tasks
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):9
NameError (uninitialized constant TestMethod::TasksTestMethod)
```

I'm getting this same error for all JoinTables in my app. 
What I'm I doing wrong? And my models are as follows:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks_test_methods, :dependent => :destroy 
  has_many :test_methods, :through => :tasks_test_methods
end 

class TestMethod < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :procedure

  has_many :tasks_test_methods
  has_many :tasks, :through => :tasks_test_methods
end

class TasksTestMethods < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :test_method
end
```

I also tried to rename the model name from `TasksTestMethods` to `TasksTestMethod` based on this error `NameError (uninitialized constant Task::TasksTestMethod)` but that didn't help.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: How did you name the Ruby file containing `TasksTestMethod`?

Comment: Wow!!! That just worked!!. File naming was the error damn. Thank you so much, been on this for almost 24hrs lol I feel so stupid right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your rb file containing this class properly, i.e. `tasks_test_method.rb`.